# Search in existing Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to Kibana. I know that we can apply search while create new visualization but can we apply search object in existing Kibana visualization?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Look at the next Url:
http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/visualize/edit/New-Visualization?**savedSearchId=New-Saved-Search**_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,value:0),time:(from:now-15m,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!(),linked:!t,query:(query_string:(query:'*')),uiState:(),vis:(aggs:!((id:'1',params:(),schema:metric,type:count)),listeners:(),params:(addLegend:!t,addTooltip:!t,isDonut:!f,shareYAxis:!t),title:'New%20Visualization',type:pie))

I took URL of existing visualization and add after visualization name new parameter called savedSearchId and add value- the search object name.
that's all

Comment: Hello Lax, Thanks for the response. I am using version 4.0.8. I am asking that i have a saved search object. I want to apply that saved search object to visualisations where no search earlier was applied. Can we do this?

Comment: Hey Lax, I tried this but it didn't work for me. I applied savedSearchID and title of new saved search. But I it is still showing the earlier result.